# GitFlow: Mergear una feature que estoy desarrollando con develop actualizado

Tags: git, git-merge, ramas-git, conflictos

Cuando creo una nueva feature, creo el branch a partir de develop. Luego cuando la funcionalidad está terminada la mergeo a develop pero hay muchos conflictos debido a que develop ha sido actualizado con otras funcionalidades.

Mi equipo me ha recomendado que actualice constantemente develop y que cuando lo haga, inmediatamente lo mergee con la feature que estoy desarrollando. De esa manera no tendría tantos conflictos cuando mergeo la feature al final con develop.

Mis preguntas son:

1. Esta forma de trabajo, sigue siendo GitFlow? o es una variante?
2. Si esto no es Gitflow, tiene algún nombre?
3. Que pasa cuando en develop hay un bug y mi feature lo hereda cuando actualizo develop y mergeo?

[image: GitFlow tal como lo conozco]

Saludos.